# Using excel MID function with comma separated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m trying to use the MID function to parse through comma separated values in one column and return the extracted values into another column.

Example:

A1: AA0221AA, BB0129BB, CC0212CC

My desired output (B1) is: 0221, 0129, 0212

I don’t want to use text to columns, because I want to limit the number of columns that will be produced.

Comment: are the numbers always positions 3-6 in each item?

Comment: Even better....would all substrings be 8 characters long with the numeric value in those 3-6 positions?

Comment: Also, if you do not have TEXTJOIN, this will not be possible without vba.

Comment: Yes, the numbers should all be in the 3-6 position.

Comment: If the numbers position always in 3-6, then you can use this formula : =MID(A1,3,4)&", "&MID(A1,13,4)&", "&MID(A1,23,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i am also new to VBA but have tested this code and this works. However your cells property must be set as text as your data has leading zeros.

```
Sub VBA_Alternative_TextJoin()
Dim InputRange As Range, Cell As Range, str As Variant
Dim parts As Variant
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate 'Change this as per your needs
Set InputRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1",Range("A1").End(xlDown))
For Each Cell In InputRange
parts = Split(Cell, ",")
    For Each str In parts
        If str = parts(0) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Mid(str, 3, 4)
        Else
            Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Cell.Offset(0, 1) & "," & Mid(str, 3, 4)
        End If
    Next str
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the work on the VBA code!  I had to add a space after the comma in the parts variable and in the cell.offset variable under the else statement. I would upvote your response, but it won’t let me because I don’t have enough reputation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),3,4))
```

In Excel 2019 this will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter to force as an array formula.

[image]

If one does not have TEXTJOIN it will require VBA.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the work on the syntax! Unfortunately, I don’t have the text join function on my version of excel.